# How do I select which div element to show initially when I am filtering divs based on their class name?

Tags: javascript, filter

I have filtered a set of divs below based on their class name.

This works well when I am selecting a filter button, however initially they all show.

I would like just the "2017" class to show.

Here is the code:

```
* filter elements*/


filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  // Add the "show" class (display:block) to the filtered elements, and remove the "show" class from the elements that are not selected
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

// Show filtered elements
function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

// Hide elements that are not selected
function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current control button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}


.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.myBtnContainer{
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.filterDiv {

    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
}

/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
.show {
    display: block;
}

/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline;
  width: 20%;
  color: #1d1d1b;
}

.btn:focus,
.btn:hover{
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.4;
    color: #1d1d1b;
}


<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('2013')"> 2013</button><button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('2014')"> 2014</button><button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('2015')"> 2015</button><button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('2016')"> 2016</button><button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('2017')"> 2017</button>
</div>


<div class="container">

<div class="wine-row filterDiv 2013">
<img class="wine-bottle" src="http://chateau.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/CUV-SASHA_2014.png" />
</div>


<div class="wine-row filterDiv 2014">
<img class="wine-bottle" src="http://chateau.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/CUV-SASHA_2014.png" />
</div>

<div class="wine-row filterDiv 2015">
<img class="wine-bottle" src="http://chateau.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/CUV-SASHA_2014.png" />
</div>

<div class="wine-row filterDiv 2016">
<img class="wine-bottle" src="http://chateau.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/CUV-SASHA_2014.png" />
</div>

<div class="wine-row filterDiv 2017">
<img class="wine-bottle" src="http://chateau.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/CUV-SASHA_2014.png" />
</div>

</div>
```

All of the years show initial in a list, and it is not until I select a year from the navigation that the items filter, I would like them to be filtered from the start, showing only the 2017 elements.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to start out with only 2017 showing. Couldn't you just change that top `filterSelection("all")` to `filterSelection('2017')?`

Comment: Ah that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well from your HTML file i see that you have already named your class and you added a filterDiv 2017 which is sufficient to filter it. You can also create an ID for each div so that you can change the preferred Div by altering with the ID.